# Format Tooltip Chartjs TypeScript Angular

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I want format the Tooltip to have this format:

`APP : 111` not `APP 111:111`

I tried :

```
 tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        title: (Items: any, data: any)=> data.datasets[0].data[Items[0].index],
        label: (Items: any, data: any) => data.datasets[Items.datasetIndex].data[Items.index]
      }
    }
```

But not workin, how can I modify this please, thanks for your help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
tooltips: {
      mode: 'label',
      callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem: any, data: any) {
          let indice = tooltipItem.index;
          return  data.labels[indice] ;
        }
      }
    },
```